# Unable to decrypt the base64 decoded string using private key

Tags: c++, openssl, base64, rsa

I have a base64 string of encrypted string and using BIO_f_base64() I decoded and wrote to a file(decoded.txt) using ofstream(c++ code).

for decrypting I used below command(terminal)

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.key -in decoded.txt -out plaintext.txt
```

this will throw an error "RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT data greater than mod".

but when I decode it base64 string through terminal using

```
echo "base64 string" | base64 --decode >> terminal_decode.txt
```

and run

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.key -in terminal_decode.txt -out plaintext.txt
```

works fine. I compared decode.txt and terminal_decode.txt, both looks same.

Using encoded.txt file I'm unable to decrypt the string, Please help me on solving this

Code used to decode:-

```
    char *enstr = new char[200];    
strcpy(enstr,"sX3/ks3+abL5B1O/o/gSywOYv0tACnRkrMxKnBVDT7yhnatfE5ox2mvQz8RyM6MSCtf2exLUz3uIQGnTnk0yqgWzaDgR2ASEXi6ap1pV+1gAPMHBdiMZeNDI86RfleIH/37p7+lW3eyYwnpKJrsHf72jUu9R+aEXZSsEDEDQ1Hw=");
    int len = strlen(enstr);
char *buff = (char *)malloc(len+1);
memset(buff,0,len+1);
    BIO *biomem, *bio64;
bio64 = BIO_new( BIO_f_base64() );
BIO_set_flags(bio64,BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
biomem  = BIO_new_mem_buf(enstr,len);
biomem = BIO_push(bio64,biomem);
BIO_read(biomem,buff,len);
buff[len]='\0';
ofstream ofs("encoded.txt",std::ios::out);
ofs.write(buff,len);
ofs.close();
```

Comment: What happens if you compare `terminal_decode.txt` with `decoded.txt`? I strongly suspect this has nothing to do with decryption at all, and everything to do with your base64 decoding code.

Comment: "base64 string" is *not* Base64 encoded, so there's not reason to try and decode it and save it in `terminal_decode.txt`.

Comment: @noloader: I think the question is meant to imply that the string "base64 string" should actually be replaced with the base64 string which was originally used to produce `decoded.txt`.

Comment: base64 string is encoded only.is that okay if I use ofstream to write to a file? do u want me to share the code?

Comment: shared code, please refer and help me on fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

> ofstream ofs("encoded.txt",std::ios::out);
>   ofs.write(buff,len);
>   ofs.close();

The `ofstream` will fiddle with bits, so you won't get the exact representation in memory. I believe you need:

```
ofstream ofs("encoded.txt", std::ios::binary);
```

`binary` stops new line processing.

When reading, I believe you will need:

```
ifstream ifs("encoded.txt", std::ios::binary);
ifs.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
```

---

> this will throw an error "RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT data greater than mod".

This means the number of bits in the message exceeds the number of bits in the modulus. To proceed, reduce the size of the message so that its less than or equal to `n - 1`, where `n` is the modulus.

---

> Using encoded.txt file I'm unable to decrypt the string, Please help me on solving this

Where is your decryption code?

If you look in `<openssl source>/apps/rsautil.c`, then you will see how OpenSSL does it. All the utilities (`` `encrypt ``, `decrypt`, `x509`, `smime`, etc) have a corresponding source file, and they are located in `<openssl source>/apps`.

Here's the meat and potatoes of what `openssl rsautil` is doing after it sets up the options from the command line. See around line 275:

```
switch(rsa_mode) {

  case RSA_VERIFY:
    rsa_outlen  = RSA_public_decrypt(rsa_inlen, rsa_in, rsa_out, rsa, pad);
    break;

  case RSA_SIGN:
    rsa_outlen  = RSA_private_encrypt(rsa_inlen, rsa_in, rsa_out, rsa, pad);
    break;

  case RSA_ENCRYPT:
    rsa_outlen  = RSA_public_encrypt(rsa_inlen, rsa_in, rsa_out, rsa, pad);
    break;

  case RSA_DECRYPT:
    rsa_outlen  = RSA_private_decrypt(rsa_inlen, rsa_in, rsa_out, rsa, pad);
    break;
}
...
```